# An one dimensional sampling version of Penrose tiles in 2D

Tags: sampling, tiling, sampling-theory

I was initially interested in aperiodic sampling for signals to address the problem of aliasing in the frequency domain. A design like Penrose tiling in 2D (which is non-repeating) can be very interesting. I do not have any references or haven't done any real work on it, but I was also a bit clueless about where to search for some rules with which I can project the 2D tiling into a 1D sampling (if possible with irrational sampling instances to increase the so-called Nyquist limit farther away). Is there any rules which I can use directly; like for example, projecting the vertices onto a straight line?

Comment: You don't have to think 2d at all, there are very simple 1d aperiodic sequences, like the thue morse sequence. This sequence can be obtained by substitution rules, like for the Penrose tiling https://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution/thue-morse/, but its probably much easier to compute it from its recurrence definition. There are many more sets of substitution rules for producing aperiodic sequences https://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/glossary/one-dimensional/

Comment: Thank you for the comment @caduk ! Definitely will look into these.

Comment: If you're in particular looking for a sampling method that uses irrational lengths, then maybe the 1d Fibonacci tiling would be of interest to you. This tiling can be described either as a substitution/inflation rule, or as a cut-and-project tiling (i.e. cutting sequence in 1d). This tiling also naturally appears in the Penrose tiling, for instance by looking along the Conway worms.

Comment: Thank you @DanRust . I was also thinking of Fibonacci sequences. I will have a look. Unrelated discussion: Fibonacci, in his original text, mentioned ancient Indian scholars, who had used it many centuries ago. Later it was found that, indeed it was Pingala who had used it in the past while writing some structures for his poems. In Pingala's original Sanskrit texts, he mentions that he was using some ancient Indian wisdom in this series. Quite fascinating.